# Places Near Me Mobile Application with Google Map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, mobile, web-applications

I am planning to do an application where User searches for Locations Near Me, shows list of location and also shows locations in a map. The app will also show the images and details of the place in another screen.

Now this application is a Mobile Application. I don't want to use native coding, but I want to do using HTML, CSS, JS. Is there any framework which is fast and smooth and can be used in all mobile platforms. I read about PhoneGap, but its a bit slow I guess. Will it be good if I use mere HTML5+CSS3 and Angular JS. Will it be fast and smooth ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Use sencha touch 2. It uses javascript, html5 and it's built over ext js. It's awesome and provides very strong features and many useful plugins though some older phones don't like it cause bad browsers. http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/

Comment: @noob They have free commercial, gplv3 and paid commercial versions available.